# Fluid Width Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, width, fluid

I am making a website here: [argit.bounde.co.uk](http://www.argit.bounde.co.uk)

I have followed a tutorial on making a slider and it works on the principle of having a `ul` of a big width and then the `li's` floated. This is then all concealed by a `div` which has `overflow: hidden`. Then have jquery which animates the `margin-left = imgWidth`

The rest of my site is fluid width and so obviously I need the slider to follow along other wise it looks a bit silly. At the moment I have given the `li's` a set width with jquery and then have img's as 100%. This solution is okay, but falls apart when the device doesn't support jQuery so I would prefer a more robust method. I cant set the `ul` to 100% as then the images no longer are in a line and they simple stack underneath each other

Can anyone think of a way I could achieve this?

Full slider jQuery here:

```
var current = 1;

function slider () {
var sliderUl = $('div#slider ul'),
    imgs = sliderUl.find('img'),
    imgWidth = imgs.width(), 
    imgLength = imgs.length, 
    totalImgsWidth = imgLength * imgWidth; 

var direction = $(this).data('dir'),
    loc = imgWidth;

if( direction == 'next') {
    ++current;
} else {
    --current;
}

if( current === 0) {
    current = imgLength;
    loc = totalImgsWidth - imgWidth;
    direction = 'next';
} else if ( current - 1 === imgLength ) {
    current = 1;
    loc = 0;
}


transition(sliderUl, loc, direction);
};

function transition( container, loc, direction ) {
var ease;
var unit;

if (direction && loc !== 0) {
    unit = (direction === 'next') ? '-=' : '+=';
}

container.animate({
    'margin-left': unit ? (unit + loc) : loc
})
};
```

Comment: Have you looked at [FlexSlider 2](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/)?

Comment: I am new to jQuery and want to code as much as possible myself so I can get a good understanding, I dont want to because dependent on plugins and be able to be creative. But thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've linked to a fiddle of a plugin I programmed that does this.  The requirements are that the parent container has position: relative, and to a lesser extent overflow: hidden and that it is called after images are loaded.  Feel free to take the code and learn from it.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhQk/35K8X/7/show/

**JS**

```
$.fn.fitToParent = function (type, align) {
    type = typeof type === 'undefined' ? 'fit' : type;
    align = typeof align === 'undefined' ? 'center' : align;
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        if ($this.is('img')) {
            $this.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'height': 'auto'
            }).css({ //Allow Height to adjust
                'left': '',
                    'margin-left': '',
                    'top': align == 'center' ? '50%' : (align == 'left' ? '0px' : ''),
                    'bottom': '',
                    'margin-top': align == 'center' ? (-$this.height() / 2) + 'px' : ''
            });
            //Size by height depending on sizing type
            if (($this.height() > $parent.height() && type === 'fit') || ($this.height() < $parent.height() && type === 'fill')) {
                $this.css({
                    'width': 'auto',
                        'height': '100%'
                }).css({ //Allow Width to adjust
                    'top': '',
                        'margin-top': '',
                        'left': align == 'center' ? '50%' : (align == 'left' ? '0px' : ''),
                        'right': align == 'right' ? '0px' : '',
                        'margin-left': align == 'center' ? (-$this.width() / 2) + 'px' : ''
                });
            }
            if (type === 'none') {
                $this.css({
                    'width': '',
                        'height': ''
                }).css({ //Allow Width to adjust
                    'top': '50%',
                        'bottom': '',
                        'margin-top': (-$this.height() / 2) + 'px',
                        'left': align == 'center' ? '50%' : (align == 'left' ? '0px' : ''),
                        'right': align == 'right' ? '0px' : '',
                        'margin-left': align == 'center' ? (-$this.width() / 2) + 'px' : ''
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

To explain the logic, all it does is sets the width to 100% and checks if it's height is greater, if it isn't then width 100% is fine.  If not it switches it to height 100%.  On images if one size attribute is set then the other one resizes accordingly.  After the size logic is complete. it just centers the image using position absolute and margining.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect does device support jQuery:

```
$('html').addClass('jQuery');
```

And then  use specific css styles for this class:

```
.jQuery li {
    /* some style */ 
}
```

If class 'jQuery' setted then device support jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to not float the your panels (li's) and set them to be 100% width of the wrapping div. Then when the user navigates, position the next panel out of view to the right at 100% margin, then animate it to 0 margin while you animate the previous panel to -100% margin. Do the opposite when the user selects the previous panel. I don't think this method works well in older IE, but I could be mistaken.

Alternatively, you can bind to the window resize event (it would be best to throttle the event) and resize the panels and any saved widths/heights